# why does this code run wrong

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to print the date with the date format, like 09/05/1998 but when I run the code I get 081/5/1998 
what am I doing wrong?

```
var c = new Date("September 5, 1998 08:45:00");

function datePrinter(){
var monthPrinter = c.getMonth();
var dayPrinter = c.getDate();
var yearPrinter = c.getFullYear();


if(monthPrinter < 10){
monthPrinter = "0" + monthPrinter;
monthPrinter = monthPrinter + 1;
}
if(datePrinter < 10){
datePrinter = "0" + dayPrinter;
} 

document.write(monthPrinter + "/" +dayPrinter + "/" + yearPrinter);


}

datePrinter();
```

Comment: Change `monthPrinter = "0" + monthPrinter;
monthPrinter = monthPrinter + 1;` to `monthPrinter = "0" + (monthPrinter + 1);`. When you prepend string "0" to a Number, it becomes **String**. Then adding `1` to it will concatenate `"1"` to it.

Comment: Other issue is that, you're using `datePrinter` in the second `if` condition instead of `dayPrinter`. [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/r3fme8bn/)

Comment: yes it worked! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you prepend or append a String to a Number, the result will become a string. And when you are incrementing it, it will do string concatenate and not add. You need to use `parseInt()` again to parse the string to Number.

```js
var c = new Date("September 5, 1998 08:45:00");

function datePrinter(){
var monthPrinter = c.getMonth() + 1;
var dayPrinter = c.getDate();
var yearPrinter = c.getFullYear();

if(monthPrinter < 10){
monthPrinter = "0" + monthPrinter;
}
if(dayPrinter < 10){
dayPrinter = "0" + dayPrinter;
} 

document.write(monthPrinter + "/" +dayPrinter + "/" + yearPrinter);


}

datePrinter();
```

Answer (score 1):

You swapped the two lines

```
monthPrinter = "0" + monthPrinter;
monthPrinter = monthPrinter + 1;
```

which leads to `1` being appended to the string instead of increasing the number.

Or, the same can be written as

```
monthPrinter = "0" + (monthPrinter + 1);
```

which says, add 1 to the variable first and then concat the string `"0"`.

---

Other issue is that, `datePrinter` is being used instead of `dayPrinter` in the second `if` condition block.

```js
var c = new Date("September 5, 1998 08:45:00");

function datePrinter() {
    var monthPrinter = c.getMonth();
    var dayPrinter = c.getDate();
    var yearPrinter = c.getFullYear();

    if (monthPrinter < 10) {
        monthPrinter = "0" + (monthPrinter + 1);
        //                   ^             ^^^^
    }

    if (dayPrinter < 10) {
        // Changed here
        dayPrinter = "0" + dayPrinter;
    }

    document.write(monthPrinter + "/" + dayPrinter + "/" + yearPrinter);
}

datePrinter();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is that:

```
monthPrinter = "0" + monthPrinter;
monthPrinter = monthPrinter + 1;
```

is in the wrong order. When you add two numerics, you get a numeric. When you add a string and a numeric (or another string), you get a string. So what happens in your case is:

```
monthPrinter = "0" + monthPrinter;   // S + I -> S ("08")
monthPrinter = monthPrinter + 1;     // S + I -> S ("081")
```

If you change the order, you'll get something better:

```
monthPrinter = monthPrinter + 1;     // I + I -> I (9)
monthPrinter = "0" + monthPrinter;   // S + I -> S ("09")
```

In addition, your day padding won't work as expected because you check `datePrinter`, the function, rather than `dayPrinter`, the variable.

---

And, as an aside, creating functions to print a date to the document is a *very* specific use case. You would be far better off with the flexibility of a more general function to just format it to the string that you want, then you could re-use it in many more situations:

```
function dateAsDdMmYyyy(dt) {
    var mm = dt.getMonth() + 1;
    var dd = dt.getDate();
    var yyyy = dt.getFullYear();
    if (mm < 10) { mm = "0" + mm; }
    if (dd < 10) { dd = "0" + dd; }

    return mm + "/" + dd + "/" + yyyy;
}

var sep5_88 = new Date("September 5, 1998 08:45:00");
document.write(dateAsDdMmYyyy(sep5_88));
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace these lines in your code and youll get the desired output.

You are getting a wrong one because you are trying to add 1 to a string in the month printer which appends 1 to the string 08 which generates 081.

```
if(monthPrinter < 10)
{
   monthPrinter = monthPrinter + 1;
   monthPrinter = "0" + monthPrinter;
}
if(datePrinter < 10)
{
   datePrinter = "0" + dayPrinter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need swap these lines,

monthPrinter = "0" + monthPrinter;           monthPrinter = monthPrinter + 1;`

as,

```
monthPrinter = monthPrinter + 1;
monthPrinter = "0" + monthPrinter;
```

**Here is the working DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/nsfqxou1/1/

Hope this helps!